# SNI in HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, android, ssl, sni

So I have an application with a customized HTTP class, based on `HttpUrlConnection` that makes HTTPS POST requests to a third party server.

Everything works fine on 2.3 but I recently got an ICS phone and noticed that some parts  of the app weren't working as usual. After some digging I found that the same HTTPS POST requests were being responded to differently by the third party server in ICS.

So I tested some HTTPS POST requests in the emulator one with version 2.1 and another with 4.1, using the dump server at http://www.posttestserver.com/ the POST requests were identical and in both cases all the POST parameters were passed properly except in the 4.1 version there was an additional header:

```
SSL_TLS_SNI = posttestserver.com
```

I read a little about it and it seems that SNI support was added in Honeycomb and I'm guessing that this is the cause of the problem, maybe the third party server is not handling the SNI properly.

How do I disable this SNI header? Or in general how do I handle this case?